# How to get the link of a table in the admin page

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-urls

For example admin/appname/mytable

I need to get the link of my tables to put in the navbar, how can I do this ?

my urls.py

```
url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
```

I want to do this

```
  url(r'^admin/myapp/mytable', ..... name="..."),
```

But django says I need to put a view

Comment: please add more details, "the link of may tables to put in the navbar" what link? what tables?

you want to add something to the admin panel?

Answer (score 0):

I think You need **Django Interospection**,

**before adding into admin you need to get your table name. and then Register Each table into your admin.py**

so try this, it will list your the entire table presented in your django app.

```
>>> from django.db import connection
>>> tables = connection.introspection.table_names() 
>>> len(tables) # this is the length of your entire table from defined DB
101
>>> avail_table = connection.introspection.installed_models(tables)
>>>tbl_list = [i._meta.model.__name__ for i in avail_table]
>>> len(tbl_list) # it is the length of your available/based on usage tables
77
>>> for i in avail_table:
>>>    "admin.site.register({})".format(i._meta.model.__name__)
```

You need to register your model before use... so try above script will print something like this, **admin.site.register(YourModel)**

paste all in your `admin.py`

then try it will work...

Comment: I think that isn't what I needed, I edited my post, thanks.

Comment: that is what i am saying.. above code will fetch entire tables from your database... you need to register your model into admin.py will show you the example...  will update my answer..